# QDirIterator stuck

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm having an issue where I'm using QDirIterator on Windows to gather the items from the desktop.  For one user, it hangs up and I'm trying to get a bead on what the offending file would be.  The following is a code snippet:

```
QTextStream tsout(stdout);

void fubarDesktop()
{
    QDir user_desktop_dir(qgetenv("USERPROFILE"));
    if(!user_desktop_dir.cd("Desktop"))
        return;
    QDirIterator qdi(user_desktop_dir);
    while(qdi.hasNext())
    {
        QString name = qdi.next();
        tsout << "name = " << name << endl;
        tsout << flush;
    }
    tsout << "complete" << endl;
    tsout << flush;
}
```

When running this, the program locks up.  I have the output of the user's `dir/a %USERPROFILE%\desktop` command.  The names from the above piece of code match that list.  So I had the user move the next file in the directory list away from the desktop and run again.  Then it locks up on an earlier file.  It never gets to the end of the list and the 'complete' line.

Initially this problem was with another program that uses `user_desktop_dir.entryInfoList()` and it never returned from that call for that user on that machine (the GUI locked up).  The same program worked for him on another machine, and it worked for me on all machines.  So I wrote  the above code into a program as a way to figure out exactly what file this was choking on for that user on one particular machine.  This isn't a problem with QTextStream, it's with QDir / QDirIterator / Windows desktop on a particular machine for a particular user.

Has anyone seen anything like this?  Looking at the directory list, there doesn't seem to be anything unusual in the list, but maybe something is lurking in the shadows the desktop directory that isn't apparent.

I'm using Qt 5.14.2, compiled with the mingw32 compiler that comes with it (g++ 7.3.0) on Windows 10.

Comment: Hmm.. you may have namespace conflicts? Maybe use `Qt::endl` and `Qt::flush`?

Comment: Which line does it lock (or block) on?  Have you tried associating the `QTextStream` with a file rather than `stdout` -- just in case there's anything 'funny' about the tty device associated with `stdout` (assuming it *is* connected to a tty device)?

Comment: This requires full example. E.g. what's going with application object here.

Comment: Attach debugger to locked up process and marvel on what is going on. If it's unreproduceable elsewhee error it might be everything, including antivirus, bad c9mpiler version (can it be reproduced on another?), file name using unsupported by Qt character, e.t.c.

Comment: Right, I'd love to do that except these are DoD machines.  Getting the debugger installed by the overlords, set up and then waiting for the user to have time to log in and watch me as I use his account will take too much time from my schedule.  I was kind of hoping someone ran into something like this before.  I have a workaround solution, but it doesn't solve this issue and I'm concerned we may encounter this somewhere else where it is critical.  That last one is what I'm thinking - that there's some unusual filename lurking around.

Comment: If you can't get access to the user's machine then that obviously limits your options.  You could get the user to generate a core file (via the task manager or whatever) when the application 'freezes' and provide you with access to it.  Then you can load and analyze the core file in a debugger to try and get a better idea of what's going on.  Not ideal though.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  The user had a shortcut link on the desktop to a remote system that we are unable to connect to anymore due to network upgrades.  The system then hangs on that link for some reason.  Removed the link and everything starting working normally.